# Converting a WIndows Store MonoGame app to Android

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, monogame

I'm very new to Xamarin.  I have a few published Windows Store apps and want to convert them to Android.  I'm attempting to use Xamarin for this.  I'm just using the free version of Xamarin. Here's where I am so far:

I am trying two apps - one was build with Monogame and one is just build on the WinRT framework.
I have managed to get them both into Xamarin studio, basically by hacking the csproj files.

I'm getting build errors because it's missing references. There does appear to be some equivalent Mono / .Net4 libraries, but things like `Storage` seem to be missing.

So, my question is: am I going about this the right way and, if so, am I missing a step ("convert dependencies" or something)?

If I'm not going about this the right way then how should I be doing this (I found very few online resources on this subject)?

EDIT:

The following are some specific errors that I'm getting from the Xamarin App:

[image: Reference Errors]

And my references:

[image: References]

EDIT:

After some further research, the only dependency I can't explain as missing is `Microsoft.Xna.*`.  The others all have different implementations on Android / iOS.

Comment: You've got code that apparently is platform specific. You'll need to abstract that away. There's not a wizard that can take arbitrary code and make it work on Android (at least not yet).

Comment: I'm getting errors relating to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework` as well, which I understood to be part of the Monogame framework.

Comment: I think you are going to need to post some of the specific errors you are getting. It's likely that solving one or two will help to solve the rest, but post a couple anyway.

Comment: I've added the errors that I'm getting from one particular file.

Comment: Why not create projects from scratch? PS: cross-post to http://forums.xamarin.com and http://community.monogame.net

Comment: It's an existing game, so I'd rather not rewrite it.  Already posted to Xamarin forums.

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to use much of your existing code with Xamarin.

However, the errors you are getting with those specific libraries are because they do not exist for Xamarin in iOS and Android. So whatever functionality you had you will need to rework using libraries that are available.

For example, instead of using Windows.Storage you would use Android.OS.Storage.

See their documentation for details: 
http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=N%3AAndroid.OS.Storage

Edit
For XNA all of that should port fine if you use MonoGame:
https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/wiki

I'm not sure why it's not bundled in Xamarin, but that will hook you up.

**Edit**
This is taken from Xamarin documentation found here: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/cocos2d_xna/cocos2dxna_tutorial/

After creating the project, you need to add the various Cocos2D-XNA dependencies to the solution. Add the following projects from the location where you downloaded the Cocos2D-XNA and MonoGame source:

```
box2d.iOS – 2D physics library. We’ll use this in later tutorials.
cocos2d.iOS – Cocos2D-XNA for iOS.
Lidgren.Network.iOS – Networking library used by MonoGame.
MonoGame.Framework.iOS – MonoGame for iOS.
```

Comment: Okay, I got to that stage with Windows.Storage.  However the XNA namespace isn't there.  Surely this is the whole crux of monogame?

Comment: Windows.Data.Xml.Dom isn't going to be available on android probably.

Consider using System.Xml.Linq instead with XDocument, XElement, and XAttribute.

What you could do is use Conditional Compilation.  Create four Congiuration Platforms, call them something like Windows Debug and Windows Release and one Android Debug and Android Release.

Then define symbols in the properties on each platform target

WINDOWS WIN_DEBUG, WINDOWS WIN_RELEASE, ANDROID AN_DEBUG, ANDROID AN_RELEASE.

Then build mono replacements for the things not supported on Android and wrap platform specific code #if ANROID{}

Comment: I may be missing something here.  I've had a look at the monogame GitHub Page.  I'd already downloaded this (so that I could create the store game in the first place), so how do I need to install monogame differently to get Android to recognise it?

Answer (score 0):

This video may answer your question.  You will most likely need to replace the reference with a PCL equivalent if one exists.

http://developer.xamarin.com/videos/cross-platform/any/

Comment: I think I've watched this video in the past.  I'll watch it again, but I didn't remember anything about Monogame being mentioned.